# Angular.js auth service: Wait for resource response

Tags: angularjs, authentication, coffeescript

I created a service for my app to use to get PHP session information to verify a user is logged in. The code for the service is below.

```
angular.module('omApp')
  .factory 'Auth', ['AuthResource', '$rootScope', '$location', (AuthResource, $rootScope, $location) ->
    user = AuthResource.get()

    # TODO: Setup permissions in database and load them
    # permissions = AuthResource.get()
    Auth =
      user: user
      signedIn: ->
        user.id > 0
      logout: ->
        window.location = '/login/login.php'

    $rootScope.signedIn = ->
      Auth.signedIn()
    $rootScope.authUser = Auth.user

    return Auth
]
```

For a controller that requires a logged in user, I want to do something like `if not signedIn() then logout()`. My problem is, this code runs before my resource was actually loaded so no matter what, I get redirected to the login screen. I know the AuthResource.get() produces a promise, but in this case, I don't know how to use it and provide the signedIn and logout functions.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is keep in `$rootScope isLoggedIn` property , and work with them , assign your response values on that, and in your controller use

```
$rootScope.$watch('isLoggedIn',function(){
 // your logic goes here
})
```

Comment: I still have the same issue where it performs the check before the auth response comes from PHP.